# How is cmake finding my llvm cmake configuration?

Tags: cmake, llvm

I am wondering how is cmake finding my llvm cmake configuration if I haven't given it any variable telling it where to find it.

I am an LLVM newcomer. I am building a Hello World LLVM pass. I am on Ubuntu 16.04. My version of LLVM is 8.0.0. My version of CMake is 3.5.1.

This is my /CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(FunctionDebugger)

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)
include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_subdirectory(FunctionDebugger)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
```

This is the FunctionDebugger/CMakeLists.txt file:

```
add_library(LLVMFunctionDebugger MODULE
  FunctionDebugger.cpp
  )

set_target_properties(LLVMFunctionDebugger PROPERTIES
  COMPILE_FLAGS "-fno-rtti -std=c++11"
  )
```

I configure and compile like this:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
```

It correctly compiles and links a shared library called libLLVMFunctionDebugger.so. What I don't understand is how cmake could find the package requested in:

```
# <project-root>/CMakeLists.txt
find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)
```

I am not giving it any path nor I have anything defined in the environment but the path to the LLVM binaries.
I read the CMake documentation, but it says that the `find_package` looks in folders under CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. I print that variable with `message(STATUS ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})` and the output is empty.

Comment: Maybe you have `llvm-config` executable in `PATH`?

Comment: Yes, I do. Does cmake automatically use ```llvm-config --cmakedir``` ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your set-up looks correct and clearly `CMake` *is* finding `LLVMConfig.cmake` script (i.e. the script that `find_package` consumes to propagate the necessary `CMake` variables with LLVM 8 set-up).

On the Ubuntu 16.04 machine that I have access to, `LLVMConfig.cmake` is located in `/usr/lib/llvm-8/lib/cmake/llvm/LLVMConfig.cmake`, but there's also a symlink in `/usr/lib/llvm-8/cmake/`. So the natural questions is: does `CMake` know that it should look there? The answer is *yes*. In [CMake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure) you can see that one of the search paths is:

```
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib|share)/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/  (U)
```

You can verify that `usr` is on the list of prefixes by printing `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH`. On my machine that's set-up to:

```
/usr/local;/usr;/;/usr;/usr/local
```

Finally, you can print `LLVM_DIR` in your `CMake` script to check which version/installation of `LLVM` was picked by `find_package`. The variable will be empty on the first execution of `CMake`, but then `find_package` finds LLVM-8, the variable is set and saved in `CMakeCache.txt`.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

This answer was tested on Ubuntu 16.04 on which LLVM 8 was installed in the default, system-wide location through `apt-get`. If you install LLVM 8 elsewhere, then there are various ways of pointing `CMake` to the right location, see the docs for [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/find_package.html#find-package). Editing the `PATH` variable is one of them:

> 4. Search the standard system environment variables. This can be skipped if NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH is passed. Path entries ending in /bin or /sbin are automatically converted to their parent directories:
>
> `PATH`

Comment: This makes sense. I checked it out and it's somewhat true. The thing is that if I add to the ```PATH``` my desired installation of LLVM, CMake somehow changes ```LLVM_DIR``` from ```/usr/lib/cmake/llvm``` to my installation of LLVM, which is something like ```$HOME/Apps/llvm```. Does this mean that CMake is looking for something with the substring llvm in the ```$PATH``` variable, and then looking in that directory?. I tried making visible only the ```llvm-config``` binary, but it didn't work. So CMake is not using it.

Comment: This would agree with what the official docs say. Basically, `PATH` takes precedence over `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since cmake 3.17, you can use `cmake --debug-find <cmake-options>` to ask cmake to output a bunch of debugging information on find_* functions. On my machine, it outputs

```
Standard system environment variables [CMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH].

/home/jiaqi/Documents/LLVM/llvm-project/build
/home/jiaqi/.local
/home/jiaqi/.yarn
/home/jiaqi/anaconda3
/home/jiaqi/anaconda3/condabin
/usr/local
/usr
/
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/snap

... outputs omitted...

find_package considered the following locations for LLVM's Config module:

/home/jiaqi/Documents/LLVM/Test/build/CMakeFiles/pkgRedirects/LLVMConfig.cmake
/home/jiaqi/Documents/LLVM/Test/build/CMakeFiles/pkgRedirects/llvm-config.cmake
/home/jiaqi/Documents/LLVM/llvm-project/build/LLVMConfig.cmake
/home/jiaqi/Documents/LLVM/llvm-project/build/llvm-config.cmake
/home/jiaqi/Documents/LLVM/llvm-project/build/cmake/LLVMConfig.cmake
/home/jiaqi/Documents/LLVM/llvm-project/build/cmake/llvm-config.cmake
/home/jiaqi/Documents/LLVM/llvm-project/build/lib/cmake/llvm/LLVMConfig.cmake

The file was found at

/home/jiaqi/Documents/LLVM/llvm-project/build/lib/cmake/llvm/LLVMConfig.cmake
```

So, the cmake is using Config mode here and the file is located at */home/jiaqi/Documents/LLVM/llvm-project/build/lib/cmake/llvm/LLVMConfig.cmake*

To figure out how cmake finds the LLVMConfig.cmake, take a look at https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure

For step 5, it says the cmake will search the environment variable $PAT, and note that

> Path entries ending in /bin or /sbin are automatically converted to their parent directories.

Since I have put the path to llvm executables in $PATH:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/jiaqi/Documents/LLVM/llvm-project/build/bin:/home/jiaqi/.local/bin:/home/jiaqi/.yarn/bin:/home/jiaqi/anaconda3/bin:/home/jiaqi/anaconda3/condabin:/home/jiaqi/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

The folder ***/home/jiaqi/Documents/LLVM/llvm-project/build*** will be used as prefix. According to https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#config-mode-search-procedure, the folder `<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/cmake/<name>*/` will be searched.